# Call this.Hide() but the Form is still activated on Win10

Tags: c#

I have a dropdown Form to show some tips by clicking a button. The codes work on Win7 and XP for many years but it has problem on Win10.

```
private void MyDropDownForm_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                       
        Console.WriteLine("Form.ActiveForm.Name_b4Hide = " + Form.ActiveForm.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("base.Focused_b4Hide = " + base.Focused);
        this.Hide();
        Console.WriteLine("base.Focused_a4Hide = " + base.Focused);
        Console.WriteLine("Form.ActiveForm.Name_a4Hide = " + Form.ActiveForm.Name);                 
    }
```

On Win7, the debug window show:

```
Form.ActiveForm.Name_b4Hide = "MyDropDownForm"
base.Focused_b4Hide = true
base.Focused_a4Hide = false
Form.ActiveForm.Name_a4Hide = "MainForm"
```

But on Win10,the debug window show:

```
 Form.ActiveForm.Name_b4Hide = "MyDropDownForm"
 base.Focused_b4Hide = true
 base.Focused_a4Hide = true
 Form.ActiveForm.Name_a4Hide = "MyDropDownForm"
```

Why this.Hide() produces different results on win10 vs win7? How to force to de-activate the MyDropDownForm after calling this.Hide()?

Comment: This seems very unlikely, and kind of interesting if it truly is the case. Are you absolutely positive, you are using the same code base?

Comment: It would be great if you can provide a [repro].

Comment: I have confirmed by a simple demo showing the problem. but how I attach the demo on SO?

Comment: OK. I made a simple demo. The link is at VBForms. https://www.vbforums.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=178029&d=1595586181

Comment: I tried running your demo-app on Windows 10, but I get an exception in the eventhandler `DropDownForm_Deactivate` because `Form.ActiveForm` is null. Is there a reason that the DropDownForm is hidden, and not just closed entirely?

Comment: @ Lars Kristensen it is just a simple demo by clicking anywhere on MainForm to call DropDownForm_Deactivate, don't click anywhere on desktop to avoid error . Are you seeing different results on Win7 and Win10?

Comment: @TheGeneral have you tested the demo?

Comment: I have tested the same codes on old VB6 language, it has the same problem on Win10 vs Win7. Has MS changed something foundational? refer: https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?887958-Call-Hide()-but-the-Form-is-still-activated-on-Win10&p=5488179#post5488179